# FIltering rows of an rdd in map phase using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

i am filtering a dataset using this code in pyspark :

```
rdd = sc.textFile("location...").map(lambda line: line.split(",")). \
         filter(lambda line :condition...)
```

My problem is this: In my pseudo-code for the solution the filtering of the lines that don't meet my condition can be done in map phase an thus parse the whole dataset once.However in this case the dataset is parsed 2 times which is more expensive.

Is there a way to do this with one parse?

Comment: The dataset isn’t parsed two times, the output of map is fed as an input to filter.

Answer (score 2):

As from your code map part is done before filtering, if you want to provide more optimization and your mapping function output is not required for filtering, In such case, it is advised to do filtering before mapping, so this way it reduces the number of the input element to map function

filtering before mapping

```
rdd = sc.textFile("location...").filter(lambda line: line.split(",")). \
     map(lambda line :condition...)
```

Also, if you want to provide some filtering logic in the mapping function this can be done, However in this case you need to filter the NONE type element at the end.

```
words = sc.parallelize(
["my code",
 "java is a required",
 "hadoop is a framework",
 "spark",
 "akka",
 "spark vs hadoop",
 "pyspark",
 "pyspark and spark"]
)

def mapCondition(line):
   if(line.startswith("p")):
       return line

tokenized = words.map(lambda line: mapCondition(line))
print tokenized.collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can operate directly on `line.split(",")` in the filter lambda function. For example, you can compare the string before the first comma as below:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("location...").filter(lambda line: line.split(",")[0] = "string")
```